# HashiCorp Vault - Deny login access to Root namespace for non-Admin users

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, policy, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

As part of our Azure AD app registration for Vault single sign-on using OIDC, we've created two Azure AD groups:

- VaultAdmins : This group will have Admin access across all namespaces, including the Root
- VaultUsers  : This group will only have standard access on all designated child namespace(s).

We also have some dedicated Vault policies setup to define capabilities for the above two external groups. I must also mention that both groups are mapped to two internal (Vault) groups.

The requirement now is to completely deny OIDC login access to the Root namespace for all members of the non-Admin group. The non-Admin group ("VaultUsers") should only have the capability to log into the child namespace(s) to which they've been designated.

I have tried various things, inclduing setting up the below single rule for non-Admin users on the Root namespace, but I'm still unable to achieve the desired result. Any suggestions? Do I need to add an extra rule to deny access to the Root namespace and if so, how?

**[[ Below, a snippet of the Policy rule for the Root namespace non-Admin users ]]**

```
rule  {
        path         = "sys/auth/oidc/*"
        capabilities = ["deny"]
        description  = "deny all non-Admin OIDC access on Root namespace"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sys/auth/oidc` path is not used for authentication. It is used to [enable](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/auth#enable-auth-method) and [confige](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/auth#tune-auth-method) authentication backends, not to authenticate with them.

Second, your [policy HCL syntax](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies#policy-syntax) is wrong, for that configuration (not login) path. Your snippet should be written like this:

```
#Deny all non-Admin OIDC **configuration** access on root namespace
path "sys/auth/oidc/*" {
   capabilities = ["deny"]
}
```

Finally, authentication endpoints can't be secured with policies because they are used by anonymous users. In other words, Vault doesn't know what group you are in until you authenticate, and then it's too late.

Keeping in mind that the OIDC login method actually delegates the authentication decision to Azure AD. Vault does not authenticate the user but it validates and trusts the authentication token returned by AzureAD.

So to acheive what you want, implement some kind of logic in AzureAD so that a user can't authenticate there (AzureAD will never authenticate non-admin users) for the Vault application only.

On the Vault side, the easiest way is to let users authenticate using Azure AD but not assign them any policies so they see nothing (but their cubbyhole). Using [the identity backend, putting entity aliases in Vault groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135568/591064) can help, but it has some drawbacks you should evaluate against the pure AzureAD solution.

Comment: That's great feedback @ixe013. Will review the steps you've proposed to identity best-fit and provide some feedback in due course.

Comment: ixe013, not sure that statement about my HCL policy syntax being wrong is entirely true. Bear in mind, the format I presented is being run in Terraform, not the Vault CLI.

Comment: Thanks for that important clarification. Then the policy might be valid syntax, but it does not really matter because you can't apply a policy to an anonymous endpoint.