# With Hashicorp Vault using LDAP auth, how do I associate a user to a group by a UID?

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

I am working with a corporate non-AD LDAP server.  The person record contains something like this:

```
dn: uid=123456789,c=us,ou=unit,o=acme.com
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: top
mail: john.doe@acme.com
uid: 123456789
```

This record contains no group membership info.  Instead, the group records contain the UID of each member, e.g.:

```
dn: cn=vault_users,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=acme.com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
ou: memberlist
ou: groups
o: acme.com
cn: vault_users
uniquemember: uid=123456789,c=us,ou=unit,o=acme.com
```

The mail attribute equals the Vault login username, and this part works just fine.  However, I can't figure out how to relate groups to the logged in user since the key relationship is the UID, which is a piece of the group's uniquemember value.

How do I associate LDAP groups to logged in users so that I can use the LDAP groups to control authorization level in Vault?  Thanks!

Comment: The LDAP user<-->group mapping is automatically transmitted to Vault as long as the users and groups are correctly discovered by Vault when the engine is configured. Is Vault correctly discovering the LDAP groups? Was that information absent from the LDAP configuration during enablement, or otherwise misconfigured?

Comment: Matt, I'm not sure I completely follow your question about configuration, but yes, Vault is discovering LDAP groups.  For example, if a create a group filter referencing a non-existing group, I receive an error attempting to login.  My question is, how do I write a group filter that checks to see if this element from the matching person object is part of this string element from a discovered group object when neither is the UserAttr or GroupAttr?  Or is my basic approach wrong and there's a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have [set `userattr = mail`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/ldap#userattr) so that user can login with `john.doe@acme.com` instead of `123456789`. That is the problem.

For group mapping to work, the LDAP attribute used for login should match the attribute to indicate group membership. But you don't want people entering the `uid` - in the odd case they even know what it is.

Fortunately, [Vault now supports a user search filter](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/11000) that should make this work for you. Disclaimer: I wrote that code because I had a similar - but different - problem to solve.

Here is in short, how LDAP authentication works:

1. User submits a username *that makes sense for them* and password.
2. Vault searches for the user in LDAP using a filter to get the user's distinguished name (`dn` attribute).
3. Vault tries to bind (authenticate) to LDAP using the user's `dn` and the password submitted.

In your case, the default filter used by Vault does not match your configuration. You need to tell Vault how to search for the user using the `mail` attribute but make authorization decisions using the `uid` attribute. If authentication succeeds, Vault will use the `uid` attribute to assess group membership.

Based on your example, you should set `userfilter` like this:

```
(mail={{.Username}})
```

Enter the double curly braces as-is, Vault will understand that it's a template.

With that, Vault's [default filter for group membership](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/ldap#groupfilter) should work because:

```
(|(memberUid={{.Username}})(member={{.UserDN}})(uniqueMember={{.UserDN}}))
```

Will match:

```
uniqueMember: uid=123456789,c=us,ou=unit,o=acme.com
```

I don't have a working Vault anymore, but this should work according to the documentation because the `groupfilter` includes the `uniqueMember` attribute. If you run into problems, try setting [`groupattr = uniqueMember`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/ldap#groupattr) to make it explicit.

+You might be in for a little scriping, adding entity aliases to existing entities so that users logging in with the `uid` configuration map to the same entity they got with the `mail` configuration. This [answer could help you get started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135568/591064).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  I look forward to trying this out.